# Does any scripture back the story of Hanuman crushing the egos of Balarama, Garuda, Satyabhama and Sudarshana Chakra?

Tags: hanuman, garuda, balarama, satyabhama

I have gone through the related posts containing the tags "Hanuman", "Balarama", "Garuda", "Satyabhama" and "Sudarshana Chakra". None of them provides an authoritative answer.

Comment: Doordarshan creates fiction out of a nucleus of truth - but sometimes makes it up out of whole cloth - like Indrajit counselling Ravana to surrender because Rama is Narayana himself  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QjYSTM7iDw  They need drama - people wouldn't watch otherwise,

Answer (score 1):

Nope , actually it is a fake fictional story created by serial directors to add masala for trp. Hanuman visiting Sri Krishna is mentioned in Parasara samhita ,it mentions about breaking pride of Garuda and then seeing Sita Ram in Rukmini Shyama. There was no mention of Sudharshana chakra , Balarama. Satyabhama was mentioned but not like in shown in shows. Actually what happened is Sri Krishna asked Satyabhama to become Sita she didn't Heard his words and thought he was joking with her so she said why don't you ask Rukmani to become Sita it will be nice.

Now it doesn't means Satyabhama isn't Sita.

Satyabhama is Sita according to Garuda puran and Adi Ramayan and Sita Sahasranamam

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am not able to add links

Comment: Could you point at the exact verses of Garuda Purana, Adi Ramayana and Sita Sahasranama that mention it, please?

Comment: Garuda puran moksha khand chapter 16. Adi Ramayanam chapter 25 and Sita Sahasranamam verse number i don't remember